# Get value from json using ptree in c++ if key name is with dots(.)

Tags: c++, json, boost-propertytree

I tried using ptree to fetch value of key in c++ for key name having multiple . in keys.

so I have json,

```
"product": {
    "product.description.text": "Some text here"
}
```

I tried calling

```
std::string product = pt.get_value("product.product.description.text");
```

but can't get value.
please help me

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/accessing.html
You may use something like the following:

```
pt.get<std::string>('/', "product/product.description.text");
```